# ToString format for fixed length of output - mixture of decimal and integer

Tags: c#, tostring

I'm writing some code to display a number for a report. The number can range from 1. something to thousands, so the amount of precision I need to display depends on the value.

I would like to be able to pass something in `.ToString()` which will give me at least 3 digits - a mixture of the integer part and the decimal part.

Ex:

```
1.2345 -> "1.23"
21.552 -> "21.5"
19232.12 -> "19232"
```

Using `000` as a format doesn't work, since it doesn't show any decimals, neither does `0.000` - which shows too many decimals when the whole part is larger than 10.

Comment: What about: `ToString("G3")`?

Comment: @PoulBak - I'm not looking to show exponents. The whole plan is that this number has been divided already, and will show 1.25 Million, or 123 Million for instance.

Comment: Well, once you have divided the numbers, then `ToString("G3")` should work - at least on the examples you have given. Have you tried it?

Comment: @PoulBak G3 can solve half of the problem. he needs at least 3 digits and no E+ at the end for any possible number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write an extension method for this:

```
public static string ToCustomString(this double d, int minDigits = 3)
{
    // Get the number of digits of the integer part of the number.
    int intDigits = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(d) + 1);
    // Calculate the decimal places to be used.
    int decimalPlaces = Math.Max(0, minDigits - intDigits);
    
    return d.ToString($"0.{new string('0', decimalPlaces)}");
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Console.WriteLine(1.2345.ToCustomString());    // 1.23
Console.WriteLine(21.552.ToCustomString());    // 21.6
Console.WriteLine(19232.12.ToCustomString());  // 19232

Console.WriteLine(1.2345.ToCustomString(minDigits:4));    // 1.235
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/CFRI89934)**.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done with `ToString()` alone.

Instead, start by formatting the number with 2 trailing digits, then truncate as necessary:

```
static string FormatNumber3Digits(double n)
{
    // format number with two trailing decimals
    var numberString = n.ToString("0.00");

    if(numberString.Length > 5)
        // if resulting string is longer than 5 chars it means we have 3 or more digits occur before the decimal separator
        numberString = numberString.Remove(numberString.Length - 3);
    else if(numberString.Length == 5)
        // if it's exactly 5 we just need to cut off the last digit to get NN.N
        numberString = numberString.Remove(numberString.Length - 1);

    return numberString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex, that will give you three digits of any number (if there's no decimal point, then all digits are matched):

```
@"^(?:\d\.\d{1,2}|\d{2}\.\d|[^.]+)"
```

**Explanation**:

`^` match from start of string

**either**

`\d\.\d{1,2}` a digit followed by a dot followed by 1 or 2 digits

**or**

`\d{2}\.\d` 2 digits followed by a dot and 1 digit

**or**

`[^.]+` any number of digits not up to a dot.

First divide your number and then call `ToString()` before the regex.

Comment: _"[^.]+ any number of digits not up to a dot"_ That's incorrect. Technically, it will return the desired match _as long as it's applied to a valid number_ but I would be more explicit and use `\d+` instead of `[^.]+`.

Comment: Also, when you pass "2", it will return "2" while the OP wants "2.00" in that case (i.e., "at least three digits").

Comment: @41686d6564: You start with a number so it will work. Also I read "at least three digits" as: "19232.12 -> 19232". But of course that's up to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to implement this just write
ToString("f2") for two decimal number just change this fnumber to get your required number of decimal values with integer values also.